# Remove linear trend from raster stack R

Tags: r, raster

Trying remove the linear trend (detrend) from a monthly precipitation raster stack for the US from 1979-2015 (https://www.northwestknowledge.net/metdata/data/monthly/pr_gridMET.nc). These data are large enough that using those data as an example would be a bit unruly here so I am going to use the data from the raster package for sake of efficiency.  The working model I have currently is to use `raster"::calc`` on a linear model and pull the residuals.  My understanding is that those residuals are the detrended series, but I am not 100% sure that is correct.  The code I am using is as follows:

```
library(raster)

fn <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
fn2 <- fn+1000
fn3 <- fn +500
fn4 <- fn +750
fn5 <- fn+100

fns <- stack(fn, fn2, fn3, fn4, fn5)

time <- 1:nlayers(fns)

# Get residuals to detrend the raw data
get_residuals <- function(x) {
  if (is.na(x[1])){ 
    rep(NA, length(x)) } 
  else {
    m <- lm(x~time)
    q <- residuals(m)
    return(q)
  }
}

detrended_fns <- calc(fns, get_residuals) # Create our residual (detrended) time series stack
```

I feel like I'm missing something here.  Can anyone confirm that I'm on the right track here?  If I'm not any suggestions on how to properly detrend these data would be helpful! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The residuals remove the slope *and* the intercept and you get *anomalies*. Perhaps you only want to remove the slope? In that case you could add the intercept to the residuals in `get_residuals`

```
q <- residuals(m) + coefficients(m)[1]
```

Or better:

```
q <- residuals(m) + predict(m)[1]
```

So that you use year 1 (and not year 0) as the base, and it would also work if time is, say, `2000:2004`

You could also take the last year, mid year, or average as base.

Comment: that is what I was missing! I just want to remove the trend so adding the intercept would accomplish that - makes complete sense.  Thank you very much

Comment: Sorry- not sure I understand why using the intercept from the predicted values would be more benificial? So would I be excluding a year if I did not use the predicted values?

Comment: The intercept is where x = 0. Your first year is 1, so the difference should be small. But if you changed `time` from `1:nlayers(fns)` to `1979:2015`, the regression model and residuals would be the same, but using the intercept would be odd; and using the predicted value for 1979 as the constant to be added to the residuals would make more sense.